# How do I fix the cable connector to my laptop(horixontal/vertical lines)?

Tags: lcd, cable, connector

I have an Alienware m14x and have gotten vertical and horizontal lines all over the screen. In the past I was able to twist, bend, and push in certain spots on the screen to fix it (mostly). Now its gone too far.

I disassembled the LCD screen and searched a piece. Here is what the tag says:

> COXIAL CABLE-1 /N 1422-0007000 WANSHIH    12/03/26

I Googled it and here are some [images](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Free-Shipping-EMS-NEW-P-N-1422-017J000-3G-LVDS-CABLE/903511_707732491.html)

This here is a picture of my laptop (partially disassembled):

[image]

I was wondering how should i continue disassembling it to fix the cable. I was told I have to tighten some pieces (cable). I just don't know what to do from this point on.

Comment: In my experience you'll have to find the disassembly guide for your laptop. Otherwise you will spend a lot of time figuring our how to do it. There is always some hidden screw really hard to find.

Comment: Solved it(I hope...) In the picture you can see the "do not touch" thing. I touched it an the monitor started showing the stuff. When i let go... it would have the lines again. I simply put a business card in between the case and the do not touch thingy. :P

Comment: Great! The less you disassemble the better ;)